# Adobe Flash Player 11.5 installation error required :3 file

Tags: windows-xp, installation, flash-player

My instance of Adobe Flash Player 11.5 always stops and says:

> The installation encountered errors:
>
> A required file (:3) could not be installed.
>
> Please visit the following link for troubleshooting tips: Troubleshoot
>   Flash Player installation for Windows.

Am I missing a file from my machine? I am running Windows XP Pro SP3.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the link leads me to http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-windows.html but it does not say anything that relates to my error.

Comment: have you tried with a clean installation?? [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4041846) is a link to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when we install software it could be problems on installation and get corrupted files, so we can always try a clean installation

[here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4041846) is a link to do so...

This could fix the problem (most of times) or make us conscious that some third-party software is messing with our OS

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting error while installing adobe flash player please do the following

1. Download [adobe flash player uninstaller](http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/support/uninstall_flash_player.exe)
2. Close all the browsers
3. Run the uninstaller
4. locate the folder c:\windows\system32\macromed\flash and rename it to flash.old
5. Reinstall [Adobe Flash player for IE](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_ax_debug.exe) or [Adobe Flash player for firefox](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.exe)

make sure even after successful installation you might need to enable the addon/plugin for flash in internet explorer/firefox respectively